# Utilizar comillas dobles y simples en PHP con Blade Laravel utilizando variables en <label>

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Necesito obtener el siguiente código:

```
@if ($plantilla->var_1)
   <div class= "row align-items-center">
      <label for="var_1" class="col-md-2">{{ $plantilla->var_1 }}</label>
      <div class=col-md-4>
         <input id="var_1" type="text" class="form-control" name="var_1" required value="{{ old('var_1') }}">
          </div>   
    </div>    
@endif
              
@if ($plantilla->var_2)
    <div class= "row align-items-center">
       <label for="var_2" class="col-md-2">{{ $plantilla->var_2 }}</label>
       <div class=col-md-4>
          <input id="var_2" type="text" class="form-control" name="var_2" required value="{{ old('var_2') }}">
       </div>   
    </div>    
@endif
```

Notar que tengo `$plantilla->var_1`, `$plantilla->var_2` y así hasta `plantilla->var_n` los cuales son los campos de una tabla.
Para hacerlo de forma más sencilla estoy usando lo siguiente:

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $parametros; $i++)
   <div class= "row align-items-center">
      <label for="var_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="col-md-2"><?php echo "{\{\$plantilla->var_".$i."\}\}"; ?></label>
      <div class=col-md-4>
          <input id="var_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="var_<?php echo $i; ?>" required>
      </div>    
   </div>   
@endfor
```

El problema es que no logra dar con el resultado porque me muestra el nombre literal y no el nombre del campo en el `<label>`. He probado con comillas dobles y simples pero los caracteres `{{  }}` me echan a perder todo. ¿Alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Haz intentado usar comillas simples si comienzas con dobles o dobles si comienzas con simples?, ejemplo **<?php echo "{\{\'.$plantilla->var_$i.'\}\};" ?>**, si el echo comienza con comillas indicas un string, para hacer un escape utilizas **'..' o ".."**, depende como inicies el echo.

Comment: ¡ _Comillas_, no _cremillas_ !

Answer (score 0):

Si plantilla es un elemento de una coleccion (son objetos ya que se instancian del modelo Plantilla).

```
{{ $plantilla->{'var_' . $i} }}
```

o como indices del arreglo (en caso de que plantilla sea un array).

```
{{ $plantilla['var_' . $i] }}
```

Comment: Tampoco me funciona. No logro escapar los caracteres.